# getting a list of authorized sender addresses

Tags: gmail-api

Using the gmail webui I can send emails masquerading as sales or support for my organization.

Is there a way to enumerate a list of authorized sender addresses?

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Google Apps domain then the existing Gmail Settings API can give you access to that:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#retrieving_send-as_alias_settings

The new Gmail API announced today doesn't support that (so gmail.com users don't have access to this but that doesn't sound like your use case).